# Extract Census Blocks using Block Centroid that falls within Buffer in R

Tags: r, spatial-analysis

After creating buffer zones, I want to select a subset of Census Block IDs whose Centroids fall within the buffer zones. I have successfully built the data for all the Blocks and the designated Buffers, but I am confused by the literature (Geocomputation in R) on how to intersect the two datasets. I began with the following:

```
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
options(tigris_class = "sf")
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)
library(tidycensus)
census_api_key("123456")
library(haven)
library(foreign)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)



metro_blocks <- function(cbsa_code) {

  st <- states(cb = TRUE)
  cb <- core_based_statistical_areas(cb = TRUE)
  metro <- dplyr::filter(cb, grepl(cbsa_code, CBSAFP))

  stcodes <- st[metro,]$STATEFP

  tr <- rbind_tigris(
    map(stcodes, function(x) {
      blocks(x , year=2000)
    })
  )

  within <- st_within(tr, metro)

  within_lgl <- map_lgl(within, function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1) {
      return(TRUE)
    } else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  })

  output <- tr[within_lgl,]

  return(output)

}

# Pull dataset of blocks
blocks <- metro_blocks(47900)

blockst <- st_transform(blocks, 3488)

example <- data.frame(lat=numeric(), long=numeric())
example[1,] <- c(38.78309, -77.07458)
example[2,] <- c(39.44192, -77.40667)
example[3,] <- c(39.41428, -77.41073)

example_sf <- st_as_sf(example, coords=c("long", "lat"), crs=4326) %>% st_transform(3488)

# 1 mile = 1.6 km
# 5 mile = 8.0 km
example_5mi <- st_buffer(example_sf, dist=8000)

ggplot() + geom_sf(data=blocks[0]) + geom_sf(data=example_5mi[0], col="red", fill=NA)
```

Now I'd like to extract only the blocks (specifically column BLKIDFP00) that fall inside the Buffer Zones. Ultimately, I want a dataset that has every pair of BLKIDFP00, Buffer Points.

Comment: You can use `st_centroid` to get the centroid of the blocks, and then use `st_intersection`. However, I am unclear about what `example` is in your code and what buffers you want to use. You may want to pare down your script to the essentials, with an attached picture to attract answers.